# How do disable INTL extension in PHP

Tags: php, intl

Is any possibility to both use INTL extension and define own Locale class in other projects? How can I disable this extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I am understanding you correctly, but you could take a look at PHP 5.3's [namespaces](http://php.net/namespace). Within a namespace you can choose any class name you want.

Comment: yes but it was in old project without namespaces and it is impossible to refactor it. But I noticed that I can load intl module only in project in virtual host settings. So thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did on Ubuntu 12.04 to disable Intl:

Edit `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/intl.ini`

Comment all lines insinde:

`; extension=intl.ini`

Restart Apache:

`service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

And with php fpm

Edit `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-intl.ini`

Comment following lines inside (add a  `;`):

```
; extension=intl.ini
```

Restart php fpm:

```
service php7.4-fpm restart
```